# 2 Magento Applications on same server

Tags: magento2

Can we run two separate Magento Applications on two separate php versions like: Magento1 on PHP 5.6 AND Magento 2 on PHP 7 on same server

Comment: Yes, just set the php handler in your vhost config or htaccess for each site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use php selector if you have cPanel.

or if you don't have cPanel, You can install multiple php version.

This site will help you to setting multiple PHP on ubuntu.

[Install Multiple Versions of PHP on Ubuntu 16.04/17.10 via PPA](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/php-multiple-versions-ubuntu-16-04-17-10)